# Invalid read of size 2 (Valgrind)

Tags: qt, valgrind

I am getting valgrind error in below line as Invalid read of size 2

memcpy(&number,temp.data,2)<----- Valgrind Error........>
temp.remove(0,2)
Here. number is in int and temp declared as QByteArray.

Comment: So, I'm just seeing a bunch of text, not code? Please format it properly.

Comment: In addition to formatting, please give more details as to which OS and Valgrind version you are using. Low level routines like memcpy often use loop unrolling which does read (harmlessly) to the next multiple of 4 or 8 bytes. Normally this is filtered internally by Valgrind, but you are likely to see this sort of error if you are using a version of Valgrind that is much older than your OS or if you are using a bleeding edge OS which hasn't been updated for optimizations like this.

Comment: Please give the printout of valgrind. In many cases, the warnings that comes before the final error contains clues regarding the true origin of your problem.